# How can we Create iOS Certificates, Provisioning Profile, IDs without login iOS development Portal

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

One of a developer whom i knew told that he having a script that create iOS developer certificate without login their portal.

I knew that we need to create ID, Certificates, Provisioning Profile, iOS Push SSL Certificates by login apple Developer website `https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action` only.

But what he is telling is he having script(may be from terminal or something else). And if we give the username and password of iOS Developer Account, then it automatically login and creating ID + Certificate + Provisioning Profile.

How it can be possible? Please can anyone Explain?

And I found this GitHub repo https://github.com/lacostej/apple-dev

Comment: if he has a script to do it, why cant he just tell you how? lol

Comment: @Fonix he may think its secret.